# Finding the dimensions of an anonymous function

Tags: matlab, function, octave, anonymous-function, dimensions

I have a function in Octave/MATLAB like this:

```
A = @(x1, x2) [0 1; -1*x1 -0.9*x2^2; x1 3*x2];
```

And I want to find the dimension of the function. One option to check the amount of columns is:

```
nargin(A)
```

Which gives `2` in this case. But how about the rows? I know there are `3` rows. But when I check the dimensions, I'll get:

```
size(A)
ans = 
   1   1
```

How to find the amount of rows of the function `A`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`nargin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html) doesn't check the *amount of columns*. It returns the number of input arguments of the function instead.

One straight-forward way would be to input any values and then find the [`size`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html). i.e.

```
>> size(A(0,0))

ans =
     3     2
```

If there are a lot of input arguments and you want to automate the process of entering input arguments then:

```
>> tmp = num2cell(zeros(nargin(A),1));
>> size(A(tmp{:}))

ans =
     3     2
```